# Projecting onto a subspace given the quotient space?

Tags: vectors, projection

I have a hyperplane in ${\rm I\! R}^n$ described by a normal vector $\mathbf{v}$.  I would like to project some point $x \in {\rm I\! R}^n$ onto the subspace ${\rm I\! R}^n / \mathbf{v}$.  If I had a basis for ${\rm I\! R}^n/\mathbf{v}$, I could accomplish such a thing by simply iteratively [projecting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection) onto those basis vectors.  Not having them, it seems a waste to go through all the effort of finding such a basis, and then performing the projections.  Is there a way to obtain such a projection directly from the normal vector $\mathbf{v}$ and a point $x$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the quotient space $\mathbb R^n/\mathbf v$ isn’t the hyperplane defined by $\mathbf v$. Its elements are equivalence classes of vectors—lines parallel to $\mathbf v$, in fact. This space is, however, isomorphic to the hyperplane.

Comment: @amd, this is a solid point.  I was at a loss of a better way to describe the subspace of ${\rm I \! R}^n$ spanned by "everything but $\mathbf{v}$".  Do you know of a succinct way to talk about the subspace of ${\rm I \! R}^n$ that is essentially equivalent to ${\rm I \! R}^n / \mathbf{v}$?  Obviously, it is also isomorphic to ${\rm I \! R}^{n-1}$, but this doesn't really capture the property I'm trying to get at here....

Comment: Well, every vector in the hyperplane is orthogonal to (the span of) $\mathbf v$, so you could denote it as $\operatorname{span}(\mathbf v)^\perp$, or simply $\mathbf v^\perp$ for short.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to project a general point $x\in\Bbb R^n$ to a point in the plane
perpendicular to $v$?

If $v$ is a unit vector, that's easy: the point $x$ must go to $y=x-\lambda v$
for some real $\lambda$, and then $v\cdot y=0$. That means that $v\cdot x-\lambda
=0$, so $y=x-(v\cdot x)v$.

And if $v$ isn't a unit vector? You could scale it first....